# SQL string Error in vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, sql-server-2008

i want to connect a database to my project 
but i am getting an error on this line

> "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
>   AttachDbFilename="c:\users\cj\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2010\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\cj.mdf";Integrated
>   Security=True;User Instance=True"

the error is 
Error   1   Character constant must contain exactly one character.
Error   2   Syntax error.

THIS IS THE CODE

```
Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
Me.PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, Me.PictureBox1.Image.RawFormat)
Dim arraybuffer() As Byte = ms.GetBuffer
ms.Close()



Dim sqlString As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename="c:\\users\\cj\\documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\WindowsApplication1\\WindowsApplication1\\cj.mdf";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
Dim sqlQuery As String = "INSERT INTO image Values(@imagedata)"
Dim sqlcon As New SqlConnection(sqlString)
sqlcon.Open()
Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlcon)
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@imagedata", arraybuffer))
MessageBox.Show("IMAGE SAVED IN DATABASE")
sqlcon.Close()
```

Comment: can you post the vb.net lines code where you get this error?

Comment: Dim sqlString As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=""c:\users\cj\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\cj.mdf"";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"                                                      YOUR ANSWER WAS RIGHT                                    THANX for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape double quotes (`"`) in string with double double quotes( `""` ).

Try this

```
Dim sqlString As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=""c:\users\cj\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\cj.mdf"";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```